# Convert Ratings into Columns and Columns as rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I want to Convert Ratings into Columns and Columns as rows in Pandas
Sample Data:
[image]

Required format:
[image]

Comment: Hi. Please post the code that you have tried as well. Thank you.

Comment: `temp  = df.melt()`, then `pd.crosstab(temp['variable'], temp['value'])`.